# How to dockerize a node.js talking to a local mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

Let's say you want to dockerize a node.js application.  And this node.js app talks to an instance of MongoDB on the host machine.  Is this a good practice?  How is it done?

If it's *not* a good practice, then is it better to provide an instance of MongoDB inside your Docker container with the node.js scripts that talk to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good practice is create Mongo DB container from [official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) and link your application and Mongo db with [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/).

This is sample configuration for your project:
`docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: node
    ports:
     - "80:80"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
    depends_on:
     - mongo

  mongo:
    image: mongo
```

Then you can connect to mongo from your app by url

`var url = 'mongodb://mongo:27017/your_database';`

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is good practice. fwiw, you can also use the docker network ip as your  in the mongo url.